# Why the video.play() can't be resolved in <script> in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

That's all my code.I already have the `<video>...</video>` But still can't be resolved in `<script>`.

```
<script>
function videoPlay() {
   video.play();
   var videoStatusText="状态：正在播放。";
   document.getElementById("videoStatus").innerHTML=videoStatusText
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to find video element first and assign to variable.
In video tag set id

```
<video id="myVideo">...</video>
```

then search for it in javascript

```
  function videoPlay() {
        var video =  document.getElementById("myVideo");
        video.play();
        var videoStatusText="状态：正在播放。";
        document.getElementById("videoStatus").innerHTML=videoStatusText
    }
```